# Chrome Webdeveloper Tool -> hide overwritten css styles

Tags: css

how can i hide the overwritten styles in the webdeveloper tools?

I want to see just the used styles, like in firebug..

greetings zukii

Comment: There's a `Computed` tab, when looking at Styles, that shows only those that are applied.

Answer (score 0):

In the inspector you can use the `computed` tab as @gvee stated but it will show the aggregate of style properties for any particular element.

It will not show you the selector information/rules applied as it would normally if you are looking at the `styles` tab.

Comment: in firebug i can set "show only used styles" .. so its easier to find the error.. :(

Comment: @zukii oo I just saw it in firebug. Looks like a feature request for the Chromium team or an extension to add in this feature.